# Android WorkManager Worker can not be injected using Dagger Hilt `@WorkerInject`

Tags: android, androidx, dagger-hilt

I am trying to follow guide from https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager and encountered following error

```
E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.example.android.hilt.ExampleWorker
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
```

To reproduce the issue, I have added the example code from the gude in the [Dagger Hilt Example Repo](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-hilt/tree/solution)

```kotlin
class ExampleWorker @WorkerInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    val workerDependency: AppNavigator
) : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.d("WORKER", "I am the worker, got dependency: $workerDependency")
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

> NOTE: The `AppNavigator` is provided in [NavigationModule](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-hilt/blob/solution/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/hilt/di/NavigationModule.kt) as
>   `@Binds abstract fun bindNavigator(impl: AppNavigatorImpl): AppNavigator`.
>   Also note, replacing `AppNavigator` with `AppDatabase` which is `@Singleton` does not help.

And this is how I start the worker from `MainActivity`

```kotlin
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        enqueueWorker(applicationContext)
    }

    private fun enqueueWorker(context: Context) {
        val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ExampleWorker>().build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)
    }
```

Not sure what exactly is wrong.

---

**UPDATE:** I have created a brand new Android project to reproduce it. The project is [attached to the issue#158843197](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158843197#comment4). All the key file **source code snapshot** is available at [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/amardeshbd/33fe07607c557b8a8f5efff9625f9c72) (if you want to do a quick review).

---

**UPDATE#2: The solution**

On top of what Ian [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355423/132121), the issue was I missed following Gradle dependency in `app/build.gradle` (mentioned in [aosp#158843197](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158843197))

```
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

The dependency injection for `Worker` is now working.

Comment: Reported this issue at the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158843197

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Update (March 24, 2021):

Since `androidx.work-*` version `2.6.0-alpha01`, `WorkManager` uses `androidx.startup` to initialize WorkManager.
For the new required changes to `AndroidManifest.xml`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165871/3438172) answer.

### Original Answer:

As per the [WorkManager Configuration and Initialization documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#on-demand), to use the `Configuration.Provider` interface on your `Application`, you must [remove the default initializer](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#remove-default):

```
<!-- In your AndroidManifest.xml -->
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Otherwise, the default initializer will still run, wiping out your custom intialization and its `HiltWorkerFactory`.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I wasn't aware of this. I have applied the rule in Manifest, and validated the record is removed from merged Manifest by using "Analyze APK". 

However, I am still getting same error. Sorry, I may be missing something silly I can't see.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and this answer solve it, thanks. Maybe it would be helpful if this snnipet (or some indication) had been included in [the Hilt+WorkManager guide](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager)?

Comment: @jorgeavilae thanks for the update here. Strangely it's still not working for me. As a workaround, the solution mentioned in [Inject dependencies in classes not supported by Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported) worked for me. However, I would prefer to use Hilt's provided `@WorkerInject` solution.

Comment: I debugged source, looks like when `HiltWorkerFactory.createWorker()` is invoked, the `HiltWorkerFactory.mWorkerFactories: Map<String, Provider>` has 0 items. Hence it's likely failing with the error mentioned above. I will start with brand new project to reproduce this issue. It's likely I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @jorgeavilae - I'd strongly encourage you to file [an issue against the documentation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697&template=845603) so that a link can be added.

Comment: I filed the documentation confusion issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158891026

Comment: Got response from AOSP issue, I was missing `kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'` in my `app/build.gradle` ‍♂️. Working now! 

Comment: nothing changed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73634284/could-not-instantiate-could-not-create-worker

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but in my case, I had to use Hilt modules with @Provides annotation instead of @Binds annotation. I couldn't inject Hilt modules with @Binds annotation.