# Can not inject workmanager constructor with Hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I'm developing an Android app. and I'm trying to use hilt with workmanager constructor but it does not work and gives me this error :

```
2020-08-18 19:01:09.989 18125-18759/com. E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate example.android.app.database.DeleteNotesWorker
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: example.android.app.database.DeleteNotesWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2328)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2167)
        at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:242)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:136)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

this is the worker class :

```
class DeleteNotesWorker @WorkerInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val dao : NotesDao
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        dao.deleteNotesInTrash()
         return Result.success()
    }


}
```

app module :

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getNotesDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context, NotesDatabase::class.java, NotesDatabase.DB_NAME).build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getDoa(db: NotesDatabase) = db.notesDao()

}
```

application class :

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
        return Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
    }


}
```

build.gradle (app) :

```
 dependencies {

.......

 //Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    
    //Hilt with workManager
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0-alpha02'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'
}
```

build.gradle (project) :

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    ............

        //Hilt
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha'

        ..........
    }
```

Did I do anything wrong in this case ? if yes please help me with it

Comment: Please post your relevant build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: This question is answered by a google Employee in this Post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355282/android-workmanager-worker-can-not-be-injected-using-dagger-hilt-workerinject Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration) documentation, you need to paste this code into your AndroidManifest to get Hilt's WorkManager Inject working.

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

I had the same problem as you some moment ago and this fixed it

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by [@Attila](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63517246/499052) works for *WorkManager* versions 2.6 and below.

For versions 2.6+, you need to remove the `WorkManagerInitializer` node as follows:

```
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">

    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
 </provider>
```

The [WorkManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration) provides more information about this.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're a dummy like me, don't forgot to include `kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'` to your dependencies.

You will get the same exception if the androidx hilt compiler extension is missing and you will also not get any build warnings or errors.

Comment: I wasted 3 hours for a fix and you saved my day!